# Finding information about the Python WebDriver API

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Specifically, I want to

- Scroll up and down the page
- Focus a given element
- Deal with "Choose a file" dialog pages

I had a look [here](http://readthedocs.org/docs/selenium-python/en/latest/api.html), in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for scroll up and scroll down can't you use PAGE_UP = u’ue00e’ PAGE_DOWN = u’ue00f’

for focus you should be ok with `driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("myId").focus()')`

for file chose it's just an input `driver.execute_script(r'document.getElementById("myId").value="c:\\test\\myfile.txt"')`

Comment: Thanks for this. Using JavaScript somewhat goes against the ideals of WebDriver. Do you know of more native solutions?

Comment: which ideals do yous speak about ?

Comment: Please see [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_How_do_I_execute_Javascript_directly?). "We believe that most of the time there is a requirement to execute Javascript there is a failing in the tool being used: it hasn't emitted the correct events, has not interacted with a page correctly, or has failed to react when an XmlHttpRequest returns. We would rather fix WebDriver to work consistently and correctly than rely on testers working out which Javascript method to call."

Comment: javascript is a wonderful, powerful tool, I dread the day I can't use it.  It's a worthy ideal, perhaps overtly lofty, to not need to use it with WebDriver, but it's merely the opinion of the WebDriver team, not a universal absolute.  Long live javascript....